# startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges needs background location enabled?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, geolocation

i need to use a location with significant change, with this:

```
startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges
```

If i use this, i have to enable location backgrounds in the capabilities of the app config?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

beacouse i am reading this:

> Getting Location Events in the Background (iOS Only)
>   iOS supports the delivery of location events to apps that are suspended or no longer running. The delivery of location events in the background supports apps whose functionality would be impaired without them, so configure your app to receive background events only when doing so provides a tangible benefit to the user. For example, a turn-by-turn navigation app needs to track the user’s position at all times and notify the user when it’s time to make the next turn. If your app can make do with alternate means, such as region monitoring, it should do so.
>   You have multiple options for obtaining background location events, and each has advantages and disadvantages with regard to power consumption and location accuracy. Whenever possible, apps should use the significant-change location service (described in Starting the Significant-Change Location Service), which can use Wi-Fi to determine the user’s position and consumes the least amount of power. But if your app requires higher precision location data, you can configure it as a background location app and use the standard location service.

It seems that i can choose between background location or significative change

Answer (score 0):

i think this is the answer from apple site:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Yes You need to enable background mode.As per apple d

> If your iOS app must keep monitoring location even while it’s in the background, use the standard location service and specify the location value of the UIBackgroundModes key to continue running in the background and receiving location updates.

[Apple Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html)